# How to make the text responsive and prevent it from squezing while window resizing

Tags: html, css

As I'm new to bootstrap and responsiveness stuff so may be there are some non standard code out there.

I'm trying to create responsive layout in which I want something like this functionality:

The `play` icon, `image`,`text` and `button` should look adjacent to each other.

I've used `font-size` in `vw`, points for text responsiveness,
 **Example**: `font-size: 1.2vw`
  but that looks not so cool.
I want that even at the resizing of the window, the text should look as it was on large screen (more evident) or the `Producer Name` should go beneath `Beat Name`

When I resize the window size the text get squeezed as I've used `vw` units for font-size

I've tried not to use `vw` but then the result is weird.

I've created this fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/qs45tLge/

resize the window and observe the text.

All I want is to make the text responsive so that on resizing window the text should not squeeze, and on window resize or for mobile view it should looks something like this.

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suwEV.jpg)

Any help would be really appreciated !!!

Comment: I removed that, but now the `Button` and the `Producer Name` are popping out of the row, you can check them in fiddle.
I want all of these items to be in the same row, but when I  resize the window it should not look very tiny on the mobile devices, as at resizing it squeezed when it comes to short screens.

Comment: Have you tried to use `rem` it's a scalable unit https://css-tricks.com/theres-more-to-the-css-rem-unit-than-font-sizing/

Comment: Well , that seems to be working , but now the last button is popping out of the row at mobile screen size, how can I fix that ?

Comment: Still the same problem, can you please have a look at the fiddle, the text is still squeezing, @SuperDJ